# Fatal error: Call to undefined method InvalidArgumentException::getlevel() in l/libraries/legacy/error/error.php on line 536

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've done a website transfer from one hosting provider to another one. I managed to make the website live in the new hosting, but can't access the Joomla! administration area.

I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method InvalidArgumentException::getlevel() in /home/u907259166/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php on line 536.

Hi, I used an FTP connection to downloaded the files and database from the old hosting and to upload them to the new hosting. I updated configuration.php with new $host, $user, $password and $db. The site is alive, but can't access the admin area. Not sure if I missed something here

Joomla 3.4

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please use the formatting that I applied to your SO post.  Please include all relevant details so that volunteers have an easier time of understanding your issue and helping you.

Comment: You can use the quote formatting icon in the editor, or just prepend the error text with `>` then a space.  While you wait for support, please take the tour and earn your Informed badge.

Comment: Please include the steps you took when migrating the site.

Comment: Please edit your question. One of the beautiful things about Stack Exchange sites is that they don't read like a chronologically ordered forum thread.  Please place all question details in your question so that all of the details are in one comprehensive message.

Comment: Try moving your site using akeeba backup, it will probably solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is caused by the version of PHP that you have on the new server. Try doing the following:

- Ensure that the new server has the same PHP version that's on the old server.
- Update the website to the latest version of Joomla (of course, assuming the PHP version on the new server allows it)
- Update to the latest PHP version on the new server

Make sure that you backup your website before updating it, also, make sure that you do the above during off hours. It's not fun when the site goes down for hours during peak time.